# How to use @ConfigProperty in a MapStruct mapper?

Tags: mapstruct

I need a **@ConfigProperty** in my Mapper.
I cannot inject it, since the Mapper is an interface.

How can I solve this?

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "limit") // <- Does not work here
int limit;

@Mapping(target = "myTarget", source = "mySource", qualifiedByName = "myLimitMapper")
MyDto toDTO(Entity entity);

@Named(value = "myLimitMapper")
default int mapLimit(int number) {
    if (number >= limit) return limit;
    else return number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `Quarkus`, seeing the `@ConfigProperty`. But you can define an `abstract` mapper and use the `cdi` componentModel to let MapStruct create an `@ApplicationScoped` CDI bean. This is described in the [dependency injection section](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection) of the MapStruct docs.

E.g. you have 2 classes to map:

```java
public record UserModel(String name, int number) {}
public record UserDto(String name, int number) {}
```

In which `limit` is configured in the `application.properties` as `100`.

Your mapper will look like:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public abstract class UserMapper {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "limit")
    int limit;

    @Mapping(target = "number", source = "number", qualifiedByName = "myLimitMapper")
    abstract UserDto mapToDto(UserModel userModel);

    @Named(value = "myLimitMapper")
    int mapLimit(int number) {
        if (number >= limit) return limit;
        else return number;
    }
}
```

You could run this as a `@QuarkusTest` to verify:

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class LimitTest {

    @Inject
    UserMapper userMapper;

    @Test
    public void testMapping() {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel("John", 150);
        UserDto userDto = userMapper.mapToDto(userModel);
        assertEquals("John", userDto.name());
        assertEquals(100, userDto.number());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was already using componentModel = "cdi", but I missed the part with the abstract class. It works like a charm 